# is there a way to group 12 swing controls to the focusLost event in Netbeans IDE?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

In my database application, I have a maintenance jPanel with a 12 controls, textFields and comboBoxes, that need to notify when focus is lost after the user changes the text or box selection. Is there a way to group the controls for this or do I need to add the focusLost event for each separately? The focusLost event will set a Boolean variable that will be used to check for updating the result set. I'm using Netbeans.

BTW, Happy Thanksgiving to everyone! Yeah, I'm coding some today, waiting for the turkey to be ready, and football of course.

Comment: `The focusLost event will set a Boolean variable that will be used to check for updating the result set` - a focusLost event doesn't guarantee that the user actually changed anything. They may just tab from field to field in which case you would attempt to update the ResultSet when no changes have been made. Maybe you should be displaying your data in a JTable. Then you use the TableModel to know which data has been changed.

Comment: Of course, but for the limited times a user will click into a field without changing anything, the current approach is fast and works well. A table would present some display challenges as well. This panel has more controls and some lists too. For a different panel, table is a good idea, and fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to set it for each component individually, but if you put them all into an ArrayList or array, this could be trivially done in a for-each loop.